# How to shrink as much as possible a built-in ListTile along the horizontal axis?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can create a **ListTile** from scratch by using a **Row** with 3 children inside. Let's call these children **leading**, **title** and **trailing**. Then, I can set **mainAxisSize** to be of minimum size and done; you now have a **ListTile** that doesn't grow as much as possible on the horizontal axis.

Consider the following example:

```
class ListTileShort extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListTileShort({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.leading,
    required this.trailing,
  });

  final Widget title;
  final Widget leading;
  final Widget trailing;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [leading, title, trailing],
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, **ListTileShort** is attempting to behave like a built-in **ListTile** but shrinking as much as possible as a preference.

However, I don't like the idea of simulating a **ListTile** with a **Row**. Therefore, I was wondering if it was possible to take the built-in **ListTile** and force it to shrink as much as possible on the horizontal axis?

Comment: can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap you `ListTile` by `IntrinsicWidth`, this makes your `ListTile` to be the minimum required to display its children:

```
class ListTileShort extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListTileShort({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.leading,
    required this.trailing,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget title;
  final Widget leading;
  final Widget trailing;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IntrinsicWidth(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: leading,
        title: title,
        trailing: trailing,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way to remove all the spaces with `ListTile` is by using `dense` property like below

```
ListTile(
  dense:true,
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
  ....
),
```

Another way to do so is by using `visualDensity` property

```
ListTile(
      visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
      ....
    ),
```

There is property called `minLeadingWidth` as well. So, you can make it less

```
minLeadingWidth : 10, //Default is 40
```

Comment: This approach does not work.

Comment: are you getting any error or just not removing padding.

Comment: The trailing widget is way too far from the leading and title widgets.